# How can I change the toggle state of a button during page load with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I'm trying to build a simple web application where the user can personalize his settings. In the settings page I have a few toggle buttons, so I need to chenge the button state during page load for it to match the preferences we have on the database.

The toggle button's CSS uses a :before pseudo selector (code below), so is there a way to change the button state with javascript before the page is loaded? Thanks

```css
.switch {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 34px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}

/* The slider */
.slider {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    left: 4px;
    bottom: 4px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
    background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus+.slider {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
    transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
    border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
   <input type="checkbox" id="privacy-button">
   <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: What programming language are you using to render the website and where is the data of the user's current state comming from / what is the data structure?

Comment: Is your webpage rendered on the server? Or you are using a client-side API call to render the element?

Comment: The website is pretty simple, it uses Html, Css, JavaScript and Firestore Database. I think that interacting with the database to get that information would be relatively easy but changing the button state when the page is loading is what's confusing me.

Comment: did you mean, you want to display the button at 'on' instead of 'off' stage?

Answer (score 0):

Adding attribute checked at input helps you to display the button as checked

```html
<label class="switch" >
   <input type="checkbox" id="privacy-button" checked="">
   <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```